# PAM SSSD Allow Local Users

Tags: linux, ssh, pam

I've got a default SSSD configuration with PAM. I can login fine as any LDAP user. However, when I create a local user on a server:

```
adduser test1
passwd test1
```

and then try to login as that user I get the following error:

```
pam_sss(sshd:account): Access denied for user test1: 10 (User not known to the underlying authentication module)
```

My `/etc/nsswitch.conf` is this:

```
passwd:     files sss
shadow:     files sss
group:      files sss

#hosts:     db files nisplus nis dns
hosts:      files dns  

bootparams: nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files

ethers:     files
netmasks:   files
networks:   files
protocols:  files
rpc:        files
services:   files sss

netgroup:   files sss

publickey:  nisplus

automount:  files ldap
aliases:    files nisplus

sudoers: files sss
```

Now `files` is listed as an alternate in `nsswitch.conf` but it doesn't seem to be looking at the files to authenticate.

How can I allow login as a local user when SSSD is my  authentication module?

Comment: I ended up just creating an LDAP user to replace the local user

Answer (score 3):

Troubleshooting Authentication, Password Change and Access Control
In order for authentication to be successful, the user information must be accurately provided first. Before debugging authentication, please make sure the user information is resolvable with `getent passwd $user` or `id $user`. Failing to retrieve the user info would also manifest in the secure logs or the journal with message such as:

```
pam_sss(sshd:account): Access denied for user admin: 10 (User not known to the underlying authentication module)
```

[Source of Information](https://docs.pagure.org/SSSD.sssd/users/troubleshooting.html)

Comment: In what way does this actually answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds strange. You should look in your pam configuration, in
the lines starting with account. I suppose that there is only
`pam_sss` but not `pam_unix`.

To find the right pam file scould be tricky, depends on the distribution
you use.

For RHEL based system and SSH it is `/etc/pam.d/password-auth`

Answer (score 1):

When I got this error, the problem ended up being that the secondary auth (yubikey in my case) should have been listed before unix auth in /etc/pam.d/common-auth but I had put it at the end. Might not apply to your situation, but worth checking

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue to @DionSteel in that I am using YubiKey for 2-factor authentication for my LDAP users (but not for local users).

I'm running CentOS 7, so the file I was dealing with is `/etc/pam.d/sshd`.

Originally I had the following in my auth section:

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth       required     pam_yubico.so ...
auth       required     pam_sepermit.so
#auth       substack     password-auth
auth       include      postlogin
# Used with polkit to reauthorize users in remote sessions
-auth      optional     pam_reauthorize.so prepare
```

`password-auth` is commented out because I use SSH key authentication rather than password authentication.

I had to restructure things to allow local users to also SSH in to the machine.

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth       required     pam_sepermit.so
auth       sufficient   pam_yubico.so ...
auth       substack     password-auth
auth       include      postlogin
# Used with polkit to reauthorize users in remote sessions
-auth      optional     pam_reauthorize.so prepare
```

First, I made my YubiKey authentication `sufficient` rather than `required`. This means that if it and any previously listed `auth` modules are successful, the user will immediately be authenticated and no further `auth` modules will be checked. If it fails, then PAM will ignore it and move on to any further `auth` rules.

Because of this, I had to move all my other `required` modules to be before the YubiKey authentication. Hence, I moved `auth       required     pam_sepermit.so` up to be on the first line.

Finally I un-commented the `password-auth` line so that local users could authenticate with passwords in the case that YubiKey authentication fails (which it will for my local users).

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I unjoined and rejoined a node to the AD.

The resultant sssd.conf had this line
access_provider = simple

The correct config is
access_provider = ad